# Подписка на сетевые события (rpc-json listener)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Добрый день. Делаю AIMPRemoteControl для UWP. AIMP Control Plugin реализует json-rpc сервер, к которому отправляются специальные запросы и он отправляет ответы на эти запросы. Саму реализацию отправки запросов я сделал, но необходимо как-то подписаться на события, которые происходят, когда rpc-сервер сам оправляет информацию. Отправка запросов происходит посредством HttpWebRequest`ов. Может у кого есть идеи как сделать это проще?